# JPA Named query is not returning the results

Tags: hibernate, jpa

When we set the value of `marketOfferId` through `setParameter` it is not returning the result. But when i replace the `:marketOfferId` with the actual value with single quotes in the query it is working 'BDEN3F'. Can someone help me what is the reason?

```
String iden = "BDEN3F";
TypedQuery query = em.createNamedQuery(namedQuery,MarketingOfferWEB.class).setParameter("marketOfferId",iden);
```

-- Not working

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = MarketingOfferWEB.FIND_WEB_MARKETOFFER, query = "SELECT * FROM VW_WEB_MKT_OFFERS WHERE MKT_OFFER_UID = :marketOfferId AND TENANT_ID=1", resultClass = MarketingOfferWEB.class)
```

-- Working

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = MarketingOfferWEB.FIND_WEB_MARKETOFFER, query = "SELECT * FROM VW_WEB_MKT_OFFERS WHERE MKT_OFFER_UID = 'BDEN3F' AND TENANT_ID=1", resultClass = MarketingOfferWEB.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by changing from TypedQuery to Query.

Query query = em.createNamedQuery(namedQuery,MarketingOfferWEB.class).setParameter("marketOfferId",iden);